# Receiving a "Cannot GET / " error in the Express application although I am handing the next()

Tags: node.js, express

I know usually that error is either because of a missing `next()` or for a router issue and I looked around in SO and most of the answers were related to a router issue but still I don't understand why I am getting the

> Cannot GET /

for this path:  `http://localhost:3000/static/magda1.png`

Here is all my code and I have the next() in there. So I am not understanding why it doesn't work as-is and the picture shows my file structure too:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

var app = express();

//logger
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Request IP: " + req.url);
    next();
});

// file sender
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "static", req.url);
    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, fileInfo) {
        if (err) {
            next();
            return;
        }

        if(fileInfo.isFile()) {
            res.sendFile(filePath);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("App Started On Port 3000");
})
```

[image]

Comment: @ggorlen : Correct, BUT does it really need it at this early point? Because I am directly typing the path to my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a duplicate `static` fragment in:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // filePath is .../static/static/magda1.png
  var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "static", req.url);
```

Try to attach the request handler to `static` route to see if it fixes the issue:

```
app.use('/static', function(req, res, next) {
  var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "static", req.url);
  // rest of code
```

Also, you may want to take advantage of express static middleware in order to avoid the file system manipulation:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
// file sender
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))
```